# How to open wireless if the function button is not working?

Tags: wireless-networking, maintenance

I'm trying to open the wireless connection for HP pavilion laptop but the function key is not working and I have no clue why. Is there another way to open the wireless?

Is there a downloadable driver for function button?

Comment: Can you enable it from Device Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Using your mouse, there should be a wireless icon down near your clock in the lower right-hand corner of your screen.

If it is not there, try going Start -> Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Connect to a network (found under the heading Network and Sharing Center) -> Select the network you'd like to join.

Answer (score 0):

The function button is a soft-switch you can always enable the device using device manager. If the radio itself is controlled by the soft-switch (depending on the manufacturer) you will need to find the driver for the function switch and use that to enable the WiFi.